# Ubuntu 20.10 Lost all files with usermod when added user 1001 to group 1002 accidentally

Tags: users, groups, reset, multiple-users

I was adding a new user {rasa} to my Ubuntu studio 20.10. I was adding rasa uid:1002 gid:1002 groups=rasa (1002)
To the audio group for privileges to change cpu to performance and set jack settings. My user is named blank uid:1000 gid:1001 and I wanted to just add him to my group. And give him my privileges. I think I screwed up and got it backwards. `usermod -a -G blank rasa` Is what I typed. I logged out and back in and all of my documents and files are gone with the GUI reset to default kde. All of my snap software is still accessible even including guake terminal but nothing else.

```
blank@blank-optics:~$ id 
uid=1000(blank) gid=1001(blank) groups=1001(blank),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),123(lpadmin),1000(sambashare)
blank@blank-optics:~$ ls /home
blank  rasa
```

##EDIT

I added rasa with `adduser rasa` command as *#root* using `sudo su`. I have tried to do troubleshooting even with being fairly new to Linux. The only thing new is when i run the `last` command it shows that my next login directly after the session of adding rasa was in *tty4*. and now when I run the `id` command I see I am back inside of group **1002(rasa)**.

```
blank@blank-optics:~$ id
uid=1000(blank) gid=1001(blank) groups=1001(blank),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),46(plugdev),123(lpadmin),1000(sambashare),1002(rasa)
```

Comment: Your files shouldn't be lost. What does `ls /home` say. As which user are you logged in now, check with `whoami` or `id`.

Comment: Please add additional information via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1321805/edit) to your question instead of posting in comments, it's hardly readable. The `id`-command shows your GID is 1001, not 1000 as you stated in your question. Also explain how you added the new user (rasa). I asked for output of `ls /home` which you didn't provide.

Comment: I apologize and am very appreciative of your advice and feedback. I have an almost innumerable amount of my music and sound engineering studies and notes gone. This is very important and I hope I can be more standardized with my responses.

Comment: You added the user blank to the group rasa and as I understand, you wanted it the other way around. However, this should not lead to data loss. Explore the other folder (`/home/rasa`) and also check the trash, maybe you find your data somewhere over there.  One important thing you should learn from this: always backup the data you can't afford to lose, that's the most important thing to do when working with computers, whatever operating system you use.